# Escape Function Doesn't Get Called When Close FullScreen in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a problem when i try to press the esc function so that the fullscreen of my app will close. The fullscreen and close fullscreen already works. But the problem is when i'm currently in fullscreen mode and i try to click the esc, it closes the fullscreen but the word "Open" is still being shown. Please see my codes below. Please click also my stackblizk link here https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullscreen-closefullscreen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.closeFullscreen();
  }


<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item mr-2  d-none d-lg-block">
        <a *ngIf="toggleClass === 'ft-maximize'" href="javascript:;" class="nav-link" (click)="openFullscreen()">
            Open
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="toggleClass === 'ft-minimize'" href="javascript:;" class="nav-link" (click)="closeFullscreen()">
            Close
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what browser did you use? I click esc it show close?

Comment: @HienNguyen. yes it close when press esc BUT the word "Open" still appears. It should be "Close"

Comment: I tried in your stackbliz, it show close text

Comment: Yes it shows Close text when you press the Open word BUT when you press esc, the word Close appears not the Open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure you can fix this issue. I have some case same with you and I fix by `@HostListener` like below.

```
@HostListener('document:fullscreenchange', ['$event'])
@HostListener('document:webkitfullscreenchange', ['$event'])
@HostListener('document:mozfullscreenchange', ['$event'])
@HostListener('document:MSFullscreenChange', ['$event'])
fullscreenmode(){

    if(this.toggleClass == 'ft-minimize'){
      this.toggleClass = 'ft-maximize';
    }
    else{
      this.toggleClass = 'ft-minimize';
    }
    console.log(this.toggleClass)
 }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullscreen-closefullscreen-qbickg?file=src/app/app.component.ts